# DIV gets pulled down even overflow is hidden

Tags: html, css

[image]
I have a header, it has two parts, left - the big breadcrumb, right - control buttons. Problem - when breadcrumb gets too long, right part drops down, but i want to hide breadcrumbs, not all, but the part that covers buttons. Below is image with short breadcrumb
[image]

Currently parent div is

```
width: auto;
text-align: left;
margin-left: 61px;
```

Breadcrumb is

```
display: inline-block;
text-align: left;
width: auto;
max-width: 60%;
overflow: hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
```

And the right button part is

```
z-index: 99999;
float: right;
display: inline-block;
```

I don't know why right part gets pulled down, i want just hide breadcrumb, cannot resolve it in chrome dev tool either.
This is what i want,
[image]
Maybe there is a little trick out there, noticed many variations of css `display`, any ideas?

**Crappy demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/a796joeq/

Comment: Can you give some fiddle link.. so that we can fix ASAP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest this for the "right button part":

```
z-index: 99999;
position: absolute;
right: 0px;
top: 0px;
display: inline-block;
```

Comment: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/qdz83oww/1/) I added the essential "right: 0px;" part of the definition and it now renders to your spec (in my browser).

Comment: works! thanks man. Thought `position:absolute` is bad habbit, but now it seems only way to go

Comment: #phpenthusiast is there any improvement can be done to your solution to also render dots `...` and the end of breadcrumb? position absolute won't let it, but worth to ask

Comment: I suppose so. Idea fragment: To do that would involve a different technique and container arrangement so that the breadcrumb itself reveals an element containing three dots that's on the right-edge of breadcrumb container `breadcrumb {position:relative;} breadcrumb-dots {position:right; display:none;}` and as width of breadcrumb shrinks below a set number, the breadcrumb-dots element becomes visible.

Answer (score 1):

Try to follow the proper concept so that you can deliver quality output.

You can use float concept to achieve this. For a better understanding, you can use widths initially.

For parent div use: 100%; For child divs use: 50% , 50% (total can be max of 100%)

Here is a fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/kiranvarthi/ybt5tc8b/3/) of the below:

```
.parent { width: 100%; background: green; overflow: hidden; }
.child1 { width: 30%; float: left; color: #fff; }
.child2 { width: 30%; float: left; color: #fff; }
```

HTML

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    Child 1 content comes here.
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    Child 2 content comes here.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want to hide left part, and dont want to depend on width of right part, as both generated dynamically. http://jsfiddle.net/mp6gr204/ right part gets hidden, but i need left part to be hidden, please note: buttons and breadcrumb generated dynamically by angular directives

Comment: I have updated the fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/kiranvarthi/mp6gr204/1/. The problem here seems with "Max-Width" property.

Comment: Ok, what if breadcrumb get's long, but control buttons wont' render for guest, it will be still 50% even hole header is empty, maybe some improvement can be done?

Comment: Whether the content is there are not.. you should have your design blocks in place. That is always good practice.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is you `margin-left` on the parent div. Change it to a percentage

Comment: added demo, my source is more complex, there is a lot of markup, but demo introduces core of my problem, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Give Positions for your div's :

Parant Div :

```
position:relative;
```

Breadcrumb :

```
position:absolute;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add media queries:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .breadcrumb {
    max-width: 50%;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 750px) {
  .breadcrumb {
    max-width: 40%;
    }
}
```